# How to customize chapter heading in thesis?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, thesis

I need help in formatting my thesis. I m using ***isuthesis*** class. 
My university guidelines doesnt match with isuthesis CHAPTER HEADING STYLE AND SECTION HEADING STYLE.

aCCORDING TO UNIVERSITY, The format for typing Chapter headings Divisions headings and sub-division headings are explained through  the following illustrative examples.

Chapter headings (at the centre of the page)    :   CHAPTER 1

```
                  INTRODUCTION
```

Division heading (Left justified)   :   1.1 OUTLINE OF THESIS

Sub-division heading (left justified)   :   1.1.2 Literature review.

My thesis code snippet is given here and the output i have attcahed as an image.
My latex code gives me CHAPTER HEADING AS --
CHAPTER1. INTRODUCTION ( want this in two line)

and division heading as --  [image]
1.1 Introduction ( want this in upper case)

```
% Template file for a standard thesis
\documentclass[11pt]{isuthesis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% Standard, old-style thesis
\usepackage{isutraditional}   \chaptertitle
% Old-style, thesis numbering down to subsubsection
\alternate

%Optional Package to add PDF bookmarks and hypertext links
\usepackage[pdftex,hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Body/chapter1}

%\include{Reference/biblio}
\end{document
```

}

below given is the chpater 1 code.

```
\chapter{OVERVIEW}

    This is the opening paragraph to my thesis which
    explains in general terms the concepts and hypothesis


    \section{Introduction}

    Here initial concepts and conditions are explained and


    \subsection{Hypothesis}

    Here one particular hypothesis is explained
```

PLEASE SUGGEST.

Comment: https://github.com/srvanderplas/Dissertation/blob/master/isuthesis.cls  Is this the correct link? If yes, please add it to your question. If not, provide a link so we can see what is behind the class.

Comment: @user961708: Could you please also add the content of 'cphater1' included by `\include{Body/chapter1}`?

Comment: And if https://github.com/srvanderplas/Dissertation/blob/master/isutraditional.sty is the package you are using, please add a link to the document (with the note that chapters are redefined).

Comment: Yes .cls class file is the same as given in the github link.

Comment: i have edited the question and included code for chapter1

Comment: Please pay attention to an edit done in question about the desired format. Chapter number and name come in two lines.

Comment: Update: Is *this* the template you are using? http://www.grad-college.iastate.edu/current/thesis/Tex/isuthesis.html If yes, add that information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would suggest using the `\uppercase{}`-command. You can put this command into `\section{}` directly or define your own command. A MWE using documentclass `report` is shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\upsection}[1]{\section{\uppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\blindtext

\section{\uppercase{Section One}}
\blindtext

\upsection{Using own command}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I do not know whether this is working with `isuthesis` or not.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correct, this should do what you want. But be careful, university requirements are strict. I guess they won't accept your paper at *Iowa State University*.

Instead of patching a class file, you can use a package like `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{isuthesis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{isutraditional}   \chaptertitle
\alternate

\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{~~~#1}{\\ \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\makeatother

\usepackage[pdftex,hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Overview}

This is the opening paragraph to my thesis which
explains in general terms the concepts and hypothesis


\section{Introduction}

Here initial concepts and conditions are
explained and


\subsection{Hypothesis}

Here one particular hypothesis is
explained

%\include{Reference/biblio}
\end{document}
```

[image: isuthesisTitlesec]

If you want the section headings left aligned, the patch is a little bit different. But to be honest, i don't think it is good  practice to use a template that implements special requirements and patching it almost to the standard.

```
\patchcmd{\section}{\centering\large\bfseries}{\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
```

Comment: If this is not what you are trying to achieve, look at the question above and try to think from our side. It is really really unclear how you want the result to look like.

Comment: the given code works fine when used as it is. after adding all the packages in the preamble of the document ( as used in question), it gives error-- Missing \begin{document}

Comment: @user961708 I am sorry, you have to be more verbose. I don't see your monitor, i have no idea what'g going on. Try to isolate the error following the instructions on [creating a minimal example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html). This is the only way to make your problem understandable for me (or any other human beeing with no connection to your files).

Comment: Sorry for the irritation. I worked out and your given code is working fine. I just need one more help. Can you please tell me how to make section heading left justified.

Comment: I added the part.